# Variables con __ en python

Tags: python

-Primero quiero destacar que con el titulo no me referia a los atributos o metodos privados de clases, sino a las variables del tipo... __ name __, __ spec __, __ path __, etc...

-La pregunta es la siguiente, por lo que entiendo estas son variables que python crea en tiempo de ejecucion y que simplemente estan por  default, en ese caso: ¿el hecho de que tengan barras bajas al frente y al final de su nombre las hacen e algun sentido  'especiales'?, ¿en caso de pertenecer a algun grupo de variables o 'features' 'especiales' de python, cual seria el nombre de ese grupo?

Comment: @MauricioContreras si, gracias!

Answer (score 6):

Esas variables en particular que mencionas forman parte de la "maquinaria" del comando `import`.

Cuando `import` es ejecutado, se inicializan una serie de [atributos de módulo](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html?highlight=__name__#import-related-module-attributes) que luego el código del módulo puede consultar.

Un caso típico es la variable `__name__` que se inicializa con el nombre del propio módulo (si se hizo un `import foo`, entonces `foo.__name__` será la cadena `"foo"`). Pero si el script fue importado directamente por el intérprete en respuesta al comando `python foo.py`, entonces, al no haber sido importado desde otro lugar, la variable `__name__` pertenecerá al espacio de nombres global y tendrá el valor por defecto `"__main__"`. Eso sirve para diferenciar si un módulo ha sido importado desde otro, o si es "el programa principal".

El hecho de que comiencen y terminen por `__` sirve para señalar que son variables y atributos definidos por la biblioteca estándar python y que tienen un cierto *significado especial* para python y su modelo de datos, en el sentido de que el propio intérprete las usa en ciertas circunstancias, y espera ciertos valores en ellas según ese uso.

Python utiliza esta convención del "double underscore" (o *dunder*) en varias partes de su modelo de datos, generalmente queriendo significar algo así como "estos atributos y métodos son avanzados, y en la mayoría de los casos no necesitas conocer su existencia o uso". Pero a través de ellos y de la posiblidad de asignarles valores y definiciones, Python permite extender el lenguaje, permitiendo la creación de "lenguajes de dominio".

La mayoría de la sintaxis que puedes usar en una expresión Python se traduce por debajo a llamadas a estos métodos *especiales*. Por ejemplo, cuando haces `algo[3:4]`, en realidad Python invocará `algo.__getitem__(slice(3,4))`. Sobre una lista ya sabemos para qué sirve, pero tú puedes declarar tu propia clase que implemente ese método con el significado que prefieras. Otro ejemplo, cuando haces `a+b` el intérprete ejecutará en realidad `a.__add__(b)`, lo que de nuevo nos permite definir una clase que, implementando ese método, pueda ser "sumada" a otros objetos usando el operador `+`.

Con este tipo de trucos están implementadas bibliotecas como `numpy` o `pandas` que de algún modo *amplían* el lenguaje para permitirle operar con nuevas estructuras de datos, como matrices o dataframes, usando la sencilla sintaxis de otros tipos nativos Python, como listas.

Tienes la lista completa de estos *métodos especiales* (que algunos llaman "mágicos", y otros simplemente *dunder methods*) [en la documentación del modelo de datos Python](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) (**Warning** es material bastante avanzado)

Comment: You are a programmer, Harry! (Por lo de métodos *mágicos*). Excelente explicación abulafia. Lo que yo no sabía es que se podían sobreescribir esos métodos en tus propias clases. Muy interesante!